# How can I return a child category from a post with multiple categories in Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm returning a post that has multiple categories assigned to it (Wordpress), and one category has a child category selected as well.

```
 - Cat 1
 - Cat 2
 - Cat 3
 -    Child Cat 1
```

There would be multiple categories under Cat 3, but only one assigned to this post. I know what the ID of Cat 3 is (this is a category specific post), but I don't know how to return just the selected child cat ID of cat 3.

My thought was to use [get_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories), and I could pass in the static Cat 3 ID, but it won't know what category is selected from the post.

Brownie points if you can tell me how to format the output like this: `'cat=2'` so I can use it in my query as an argument.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I was using the wrong function.

I should have used wp_get_post_categories

```
    <?php 
$catString = "cat=";
// this is the ID of the Parent category, might change per db
$parent = 6;
$cats = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);
foreach($cats as $cat) {
    if(cat_is_ancestor_of( $parent , $cat ))
        $catString .= $cat . ",";
}
?>
```

And the output is `cat=1,2,3,` which is still accepted into the query with the , on the end.